# Should I need to unschedule my tick method?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, collision-detection

I'm trying to simulate a flick in cocos2d and I need to create a ball every time the users touch is ended, but I can't get the ball to move during the tick method, and I can't destroy the ball (which is a b2body) afterwards without unscheduling the method every time.

```c
- (void) ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    touch = [touches anyObject];
    location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

    endPoint = location;
    force = b2Vec2(endPoint.x - startPoint.x ,endPoint.y - startPoint.y);

    if ((force.x != 0) || (force.y != 0)) {
        if (ballCount == 0) {
            ball.position = startPoint;
            [self createBall]; - Here i create the ball every time
            [self schedule: @selector(tick:)]; -I schedule the tick method right after the ball is created
            [self scheduleOnce:@selector(kick) delay:0]; - This is the only place the ball will launch. For some reason I can't get the kick method to work any where else
        }
    }

- (void)kick
{
    int speed = 30;
    float32 setSpeed = speed/sqrt(powf(force.x,2) + powf(force.y, 2));

    b2Vec2 ballSpeed = b2Vec2(force.x * setSpeed, force.y * setSpeed);
    _ballBody->SetLinearVelocity(ballSpeed);
}

- (void)tick:(ccTime) dt {
    _world->Step(dt, 10, 10);
    ballData = (__bridge CCSprite *)_ballBody->GetUserData();

    ballData.position = ccp(_ballBody->GetPosition().x * PTM_RATIO,
                        _ballBody->GetPosition().y * PTM_RATIO);
    ballData.rotation = -1 * CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(_ballBody->GetAngle());

    std::set<b2Body *>toDestroy;

    //takes collisions from contact listener
    std::vector<MyContact>::iterator pos;
    for(pos = _contactListener->_contacts.begin();
        pos != _contactListener->_contacts.end(); ++pos) {
        MyContact contact = *pos;
        bodyA = contact.fixtureA->GetBody();
        bodyB = contact.fixtureB->GetBody();
        if (bodyA->GetUserData() != NULL && bodyB->GetUserData() != NULL) {
            spriteA = (__bridge CCSprite *) bodyA->GetUserData();
            spriteB = (__bridge CCSprite *) bodyB->GetUserData();
            contactPositionX = spriteA.position.x;
            contactPositionY = spriteB.position.y;
            if (spriteA.tag == kCurrentItem && spriteB.tag == 8)
            {
                NSLog(@"contact");
                [self removeChild:spriteA cleanup:YES];
                [self removeChild:spriteB cleanup:YES];
                toDestroy.insert(bodyA);
                toDestroy.insert(bodyB);
                [self unschedule:@selector(tick:)]; (i unschedule the tick method every time which in turn messes up my other sprites.)
            }
        }
    }

    for(std::set<b2Body *>::iterator pos2 = toDestroy.begin(); pos2 != toDestroy.end(); ++pos2)
    {
        b2Body *body = *pos2;
        _world->DestroyBody(body);
    }
    toDestroy.clear();
}
```

Comment: separate world step out into a different, always scheduled method?

Comment: I will try that later, but how do different scheduled methods affect performance? I will most likely have one temporary method to track the position of the ball when it is launched, and the other to detect collisions between the ball and about 40 sprites (these only have b2bodies for collision detection).

Comment: it won't affect performance